# Item to column with value from other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to change dataframe like this

| date | item_code | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | HTA-01 | 16 |
| 2023-01-01 | HTA-02 | 29 |
| 2023-01-01 | HTB-07 | 1 |
| 2023-01-02 | HTA-01 | 18 |
| 2023-01-02 | HTA-02 | 34 |

to this in python

| date | HTA-01 | HTA-02 | HTB-07 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 16 | 29 | 1 |
| 2023-01-02 | 18 | 34 | nan |

Each unique value from item_code become column. The value from its is from qty column. This is sample data to try

```
data = { 'date': ['2023-01-01','2023-01-01','2023-01-01','2023-01-02', '2023-01-02'],
'item_code':['HTA-01', 'HTA-02', 'HTB-07', 'HTA-01', 'HTA-02'],
'qty':['16', '29', '1', '18', '34'],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Comment: `df.pivot(index='date', columns='item_code', values='qty')`

Comment: Ah yes, i dont know it is pivot

Answer (score 1):

Use `pivot`:

```
data = { 'date': ['2023-01-01','2023-01-01','2023-01-01','2023-01-02', '2023-01-02'],
'item_code':['HTA-01', 'HTA-02', 'HTB-07', 'HTA-01', 'HTA-02'],
'qty':['16', '29', '1', '18', '34'],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.pivot(index='date', columns='item_code')
#Output
#              qty              
#item_code  HTA-01 HTA-02 HTB-07
#date                           
#2023-01-01     16     29      1
#2023-01-02     18     34    NaN
```

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions. Instead [vote to close](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), since you have the required reputation.